# RDLC sub reports in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I want to learn about how to use sub reports in RDLC in ASP.Net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best resource for RDLC reporting (all I have ever needed I just got it from this website): [gotreportviewer](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/). You can find a section for subreports in this site [here](http://gotreportviewer.com/subreports/index.html).

Also you can find a good resources in MSDN.